# How to create tables with correct data fomat in sql?

Tags: python, sql

In my sql query, I am getting the output as below.

```
insert into terminationdata (Name,Date,Calls,Answered_Calls,Total_Minutes) values('XXX',2021-12-17,'480298','120758.0','391238.6333') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),Date=VALUES(Date),calls=VALUES(calls),Answered_Calls=VALUES(Answered_Calls),Total_Minutes=VALUES(Total_Minutes)
```

I have created a new table as below to save all the data.

```
create table terminationdata(
   Name VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
   Date DATETIME NULL ,
   Calls INT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   Answered_Calls INT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   Total_Minutes DECIMAL(8,2) NULL
 
  
);
```

The query is working fine but the date is not correctly fetched in table. In table the date is shown as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How should I get the correct date(ex-2021/12/19)?

I have tried `Date DATE NULL` instead of `Date DATETIME NULL` .But the same error is there.

Comment: Which dbms? DATETIME is a product specific data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encapsulate your `datetime` value with single quotes. It will be automatically cast to `datetime` (if your string value is a valid datetime).

```
insert into terminationdata (Name,Date,Calls,Answered_Calls,Total_Minutes) values('XXX','2021-12-17','480298','120758.0','391238.6333') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name),Date=VALUES(Date),calls=VALUES(calls),Answered_Calls=VALUES(Answered_Calls),Total_Minutes=VALUES(Total_Minutes)
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked. But How I should get only 2021-12-17 only instead of 2021-12-07 00:00:00?

Comment: Date date NULL ,